# How to get length of a CString (UTF8String)in Swift?

Tags: swift, c-strings, string-length

i am having a CString

```
let parameterCString = (parameter as NSString).UTF8String
```

now i want to find the length of parameterCString as i want to use

```
let UTF8parameter  = NSData(bytes: parameterCString, length: )
```

and also does this means same

```
let UTF8parameter:NSData = parameter.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the strlen() function.

```
let aString:String = "myString"
let aCString = aString.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let length = strlen(aCString)// returns a UInt
let UTF8parameter = NSData(bytes: aCString, length: length)
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's UTF8 you want, the easiest way is

```
let param = "my Swïft stríng"
let utf8Bytes = [UInt8](param.utf8)
let utf8Length = utf8Bytes.count // 17
let utf8Data = NSData(bytes: utf8Bytes, length: utf8Length)
```

If you want a null byte on the end

```
let nullTerminatedBytes = utf8Bytes + [0]
let nullTerminatedLength = nullTerminatedBytes.count // 18
let nullTerminatedData = NSData(bytes: nullTerminatedBytes, length: nullTerminatedLength)
```